# Execution of a remote Bash script in GitHub fails with various methods - Maybe due to Windows10

Tags: bash, windows, curl, remote, syntax

I have this [remote Bash script](https://github.com/benqzq/uncwe/blob/master/install.sh) In GitHub that I already executed successfully line by line, several times (in different versions).

As it is quite frustrating to copy paste all lines each test, I tried to execute the remote Bash script by its **raw form** with `curl`, but it fails in various tries:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benqzq/uncwe/master/install.sh)
```

or

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benqzq/uncwe/master/install.sh | bash
```

Both failed totally after about 3 seconds with the error:

> /dev/fd/63: line 7: $'\r': command not found

I theorized I might need to translate out all carriage returns, hence tried:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benqzq/uncwe/master/install.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
```

This brought partial execution of the script. For example, while `apt-get install`, `export`,`git clone`, `rm -rf ${repo}/.git/`, and a few other operations went fine, the `wget`/`unzip` and processing of a few files with leading tabs failed to be processed correctly.

I thought it might be that GitHub GUI changes leading whitespaces from tab to space and vice versa, in some sections in the code, so I tried to change all leading whitespaces into tabulations:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benqzq/uncwe/master/install.sh | sed "s/^ */\t/" | tr -d '\r' | bash
```

The result was seemingly identical to the previous one.

Due these 4 ways fail, I wonder what else is available. Sadly I've yet to find other examples in Google.

Maybe I'm having these problems because I usually work from Windows 10 and carriage returns are added to each file, but than one could ask why did "translating them out" as in of the code examples resulted in bad execution.

Comment: Unless there are reasons for doing so, I would suggest sticking with `curl -s -L https://.... | tr -d '\r' | bash -x`, which show the commands being executed, follows redirections and removes carridge returns. The raw content does seem to have lines ending \r\n, so you will need to remove the \r. Bash is not python, you don't need to worry about indentation. Can you edit your question to explain what is failing once you have removed the \r, or clarify that you want to know why things fail if you don't remove the \r.

Comment: You might find this article helpful to configure github to not store the \r characters. https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `dos2unix`.

I installed it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

I then ran the `curl`, to download the content to `stdout`. I piped the content in stdout through `dos2unix` to change it, then through `bash` to execute it.

```
sudo curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benqzq/ulcwe/master/install.sh | dos2unix | bash
```